# Netbeans profiler retained memory calculated wrong?

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X903.png

That's a screenshot from the profiler. The last column is supposed to be Retained size.

It says that "scores" is a ConcurrentHashMap with retained size 72.

It has a property "segments" with retained size 152.

How is that possible? Shouldn't the retained size of an object be the sum of retained sizes of its properties? How do I find out the actual size of a ConcurrentHashMap?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the retained size of an object be the sum of retained sizes of its properties?

No, any referenced object can also be referenced otherwise. Retained size is the sum of the sizes of the objects that would be garbage collected if the object under consideration was eligible for garbage collection.